# How to execute this logical statement in excel?

Tags: excel

I have the results of a survey in an excel spreadsheet. My end goal is to make a graph showing the % of women that answered "Yes" on a particular question vs. the % of men that answered "Yes" on that question.

I started with this:

> IF(AND(Q1:Q500="Female",K1:500="Yes"), ?, ?)

But I have no idea how to proceed. Help?

Comment: Thank you all for the responses! This was immensely helpful!

Comment: Just a note that it is customary to up-vote or accept answers that you found helpful :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the excel function `countifs()` to count the number of rows that match your criteria.  For example if you had gender information (male/female) in column A, and Yes/No information in column B, the formula would look like: `=COUNTIFS(A:A,"Female",B:B,"Yes")`.

Then you could calculate the percentage of males that answered "Yes" before you compute the percentages in other cells.  You'd then have to repeat this for each question, before you plot the results.

Answer (score 0):

Pivot Tables is more appropriate for this. And it does not require writing any formula :)

Answer (score 0):

Pivot table is a great choice as Litmus mentioned but if you want formulas.  Here is one method.

Say your data is formatted like this:

[image]

---

You can get the count of males that answered yes on question one like this:

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A13,"=M",B2:B13,"=YES")
```

Females is similarly done like this:

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A13,"=F",B2:B13,"=YES")
```

---

Percentage of females could be done like this:
     `=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$13,"=F",B2:B13,"=YES")/(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$13,"=F",B2:B13,"=YES")+COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$13,"=M",B2:B13,"=YES"))`

Percentage of males could be done like this:
     `=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$13,"=M",B2:B13,"=YES")/(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$13,"=F",B2:B13,"=YES")+COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$13,"=M",B2:B13,"=YES"))`

---

The last two equations are in B15 and B16 respectively.  Now you can drag this accros for all questions and the results will look like this:

[image]